# Exclude matchdata and select only parentheses in regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I got this regex `(?<==).*?\)(\w|)+` that captures any text after an `=` until a closing parentheses.

I need to do an improvement on this, exluding the second matchdata, i dont need that string that is after *"objectClass"* and I need to select only parentheses from first matchdata

Here's an example of what I got so far

http://rubular.com/r/9TMcrGT1of

Comment: You will see that those offering answers have interpreted your question differently. Two of us assumed that you did not want to match any string following the specific string `"objectClass="`; one did not.

Comment: ...You need to clarify the question. Please state the question in words, at the outset, without reliance on the link. Something like, "I wish to obtain the first match in a string that is preceded by an equals sign and is followed by the first right parenthesis encountered." or "I wish to match a string for all substrings that follow an equal sign and precede the first right parenthesis, with the proviso that the equal sign is not immediately preceded by the string `"objectClass"`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, I see, sorry, I haven't expressed myself very clearly. I opened another topic about what I really need. Thanks for the effort anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be:

`(?<!objectClass=)(?<==)[^()]+(?:\([^)]+\)[^()]*)+`

[Regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/WrHRr1p3jK)

That would match:

- `(?<!objectClass=)` Negative lookbehind to assert what is on the left is not `objectClass=`
- `(?<==)` Positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is an equals sign
- `[^()]+` Match not an opening or closing parenthesis one or more times
- `(?:`

  - `\(` Match opening parenthesis
  - `[^)]+` Match not a closing parenthesis one or more times
  - `\)` Match closing parenthesis
  - `[^()]*` Followed by matching not an opening or closing parenthesis zero or more times
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat one or more times

Comment: Your regex matches `"group(maca)"` in the string `"(&(objectClass=group(maca)))"`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, this is about excluding the second match data as the OP does not use `objectClass` in the given regex in the question.

Comment: I don't follow. Why would the OP specifically mention the string `"objectClass"` if that were not relevant? Ah, on re-reading, I see what you mean.

Comment: I saw [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190017/regex-to-get-parenthesis-from-specifc-part-of-string) with additional data. I have updated my answer. @CarySwoveland Has a point in asking if `"objectClass"` should be part of the string?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. No, "objectClass" should be rejected by the regex

Comment: @RaphaelTelatim Ok, I added a negative lookbehind to make sure that there is no match when preded by `objectClass=`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Almost there. When string does not have any parentheses it still get the entire text, look at `(&(cn=Developer) (objectClass=group))` for example

Comment: @RaphaelTelatim What you could do is match not an opening or closing parenthesis before that. So the regex would match not an opening or closing parenthesis, then a repeating pattern of text between parenthesis followed by matching not an opening or closing parenthesis again .http://rubular.com/r/WrHRr1p3jK

Answer (score 0):

The following does not depend on the presence of spaces.

```
r = /
    (?<!objectClass) # do not match "objectClass"
    =                # match "="
    .*?              # match any number of characters lazily
    (?=\))           # match a right parentheses in a positive lookahead
    /x               # free-spacing regex definition mode

test=<<_.lines.map(&:chomp)
(&(cn=Te(st)ing) (objectClass=group))
(&(cn=Te(st)ing)(objectClass=group))
(&(cn=Banana (maca)) (objectClass=group))
(&(cn=Banana (maca))(objectClass=group))
_

test.each { |s| puts "#{s} -> #{s.scan r}" }
(&(cn=Te(st)ing) (objectClass=group))     -> ["=Te(st"]
(&(cn=Te(st)ing)(objectClass=group))      -> ["=Te(st"]
(&(cn=Banana (maca)) (objectClass=group)) -> ["=Banana (maca"]
(&(cn=Banana (maca))(objectClass=group))  -> ["=Banana (maca"]
```